# How do I get the estimate shipping Country id in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, checkout, cart

I am writing a custom shipping rates module, and I can’t seem to figure out how to get the estimate shipping Country ID.

I know how to get the Country id once the order has been created, but not for the estimate shipping portion of the checkout process

Any input is greatly appreciated!

For Magento 1.9 I used this

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getData('country_id')
```

Or

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getBillingAddress()->getData('country_id');
```

Comment: Hi did you got the solution for this question

Answer (score 3):

> An **interest fact about Magento2** That magento2 **does not save
>   shipping address address and billing address**  to quote until click
>   on Place Order  button at `frontend`.

### Save Process

> *If you will check at  database table `quote_address` during checkout,then you can understand.*. Basically at browser local
>   storage,Magento save *shipping and billing address and  save during
>   click on place Order*  .

If you Digg  on ***shipping estimation then you can understand that magento only need  address attribute field `country_id,region,region_id,city` etc need for  calculate the shipping rates*** .

At frontend checkout,***Magento  send address fields value from existing address or newly created  address***.

Answer (score 1):

> Magento 2.3.5

```
 private $cart;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart
) {
    $this->cart = $cart;
} 

public function ()
{
   
    $estimated_country = $this->cart->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getCountryId();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inject `\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session` in your constructor.

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
 */
protected $_checkoutSession;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
)
{
    $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;

}
```

And then, we can get:

```
 $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getCity();
 $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getCountryId();
 $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getBillingAddress()->getCountryId();
```

**UPDATE:**

For the estimation shipping country, we can try:

```
/** @var \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\EstimateAddressInterface $estimatedAddress */
$estimatedAddress->getCountryId();
```

Comment: Thanks for replay but this not working in custom module model, Call \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session using objectManager $countryId = $checkoutSession->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getCountryId(); it's return NULL

Comment: Currently, you login into your account?

Comment: No i am not login into my account

Comment: I have just updated my answer, we should try: `Magento\Quote\Api\Data\EstimateAddressInterface`.

Comment: it also return null data with login or logout

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checkout session, I think you have to use checkout Cart

```
    protected $_checkoutCart;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $checkoutCart
    )
    {
        $this->_checkoutCart = $checkoutCart;

    }
```

And Then :

```
    $this->_checkoutCart->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getData();
```

Comment: With out login it return null  , i used $this->_checkoutCart->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getCountryId();